# Radius and surface temp of red giant Sun

Tags: the-sun, stellar-evolution, red-giant

There is wildly conflicting information going around about the predicted parameters of the Sun as a red giant. The estimates for the radius vary from 100 to even 256 solar radii (with the larger estimates being more popular recently), and the surface temperature ranging from 2k-3k Kelvin to even as high as 4k (as compared to the current ~5772 K). So what's actually our best and most educated guess about these as of now, and why?

I'm asking out of curiosity, because this obviously has significant effects on the habitability of planets when simulated in Universe Sandbox.

Comment: I suppose it kinda does, thanks.